# POSTGRESQL :INSERT INTO ... SELECT with auto generated column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have two tables A(id, col1, col2) and B(col3, col4, col5, col6)

the column "id" in table A is an auto generated, not null, primary key.

To insert data from table B to table A, I am trying

```
INSERT INTO A(col1, col2)
(SELECT col3, col4 from B)
```

This statement throws error

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, "abc", "def")
```

I also tried

```
INSERT INTO A(id, col1, col2)
(SELECT DEFAULT, col3, col4 from B)
```

this throws error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
```

Why is postgres not auto generating value for column "id" ? The query works if I provide "id" from table B, or if I insert single row (without select) and providing "DEFAULT" keyword for auto generated column.

EDIT:
Table creation query

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
id bigint NOT NULL, 
col1 character varying(10), 
col2 character varying(10), 
CONSTRAINT A_pk PRIMARY KEY (id) 
); 
ALTER TABLE A OWNER TO user1; 

CREATE SEQUENCE A_id_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NO MINVALUE 
NO MAXVALUE 
CACHE 1; 

ALTER TABLE A_id_seq OWNER TO user1; 

ALTER SEQUENCE A_id_seq OWNED BY A.id;
```

Comment: Share create table query you had used to create the table.

Comment: @Code-Monk CREATE TABLE A ( id bigint NOT NULL, col1 character varying(10), col2 character varying(10), CONSTRAINT A_pk PRIMARY KEY (id) ); ALTER TABLE A OWNER TO user1; CREATE SEQUENCE A_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1; ALTER TABLE A_id_seq OWNER TO user1; ALTER SEQUENCE A_id_seq OWNED BY A.id;

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an explicit sequence.  Just define the column as `serial` or `bigserial`:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id bigserial NOT NULL, 
    col1 character varying(10), 
    col2 character varying(10), 
    CONSTRAINT A_pk PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
```

Then the insert will be fine.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf1c6) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO A(col1, col2)
(SELECT col3, col4 from B)
```

Fails because the default value hasn't been set for id. The default value should be to take the nextval from the sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE A_id_seq 
  START WITH 1 
  INCREMENT BY 1 
  NO MINVALUE 
  NO MAXVALUE 
  CACHE 1; 

CREATE TABLE A 
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('A_id_seq'::regclass), 
  col1 character varying(10), 
  col2 character varying(10), 
  CONSTRAINT A_pk PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
```

Or you can use bigserial instead of bigint in your create table to have the sequence created and the default set automatically for you. The end result is the same.